# How to check if any field of array not contains substring in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

How to check if any field of array not contains substring in Postgres?

```
$ select * from blogs;
 id  |   comments
-------+---------------
 1 | {str1,str2,str3}
 2 | {_substr_,str2,str3}
```

What I expected is like this:

```
> select * from mytable where ANY(comments)  not like '%substr%';
     id  |   comments
    -------+---------------
     1 | {str1,str2,str3}
```

If I use `unnest`, I will get unpacked array joined with every record(Not expected) like this：https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9997TuKMMzFUUuyr5VJX7a/0

```
 > select * from (select id,unnest(comments) as cmts from t1) tmp where cmts not like '%substr%'
  id  | cmts
-------+------
 1 | str1
 1 | str2
 1 | str3
 2 | str2
 2 | str3
```

If I use `array_to_string(array, delimiter)` with `not like`, I could get what I wanted as following

```
  > select * from (select id,array_to_string(comments, ',') as cmts from blogs) tmp where cmts not like '%substr%';
 id  |      cmts
-------+----------------
 1 | str1,str2,str3
```

However, there is a limit: `*substr*` cann't contains `delimiter`:

```
# select * from (select id,array_to_string(comments, ',') as cmts from blogs) tmp where cmts not like '%str1,str2%';
 id  |        cmts
-------+--------------------
 2 | _substr_,str2,str3
```

Is there any better way to filter the whole row if any field of  `comments`  **not contains specified substring**?

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/228235/match-string-pattern-to-any-array-element/228262#228262

Answer (score 1):

If you have a unique id in your table, you can do it like this ([result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/inpagmTUCar8R5aaU6aHxe/0))

```
with x as (select *,unnest(arrays) as to_text from t1)
select t1.*
from t1,x 
where x.to_text ilike '%sutstr%'
and x.id = t1.id
```

Comment: there are no integrated functions to do what you need. What's wrong with my solution ?

Comment: if at least one field of the array contains `%substr%` it will return the row otherwise it won't. Isn't that the way you want it to run ?

Comment: It could not filter the whole row with unnest for this example:` select * from (select id,unnest(comments) as cmts from t1) tmp where cmts not like '%substr%'
`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `unnest` function.

```
select *
from (
  select *,unnest(arrays) as val 
  from mytable
) tt 
WHERE pub_types like '%sutstr%'
```

If you don't want to unpack arrays, another way you can try to use `ARRAY_TO_STRING` function with `LIKE`.

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
where ARRAY_TO_STRING(pub_types, ',') LIKE '%sutstr%'
```

Comment: Why don't you want to unpack arrays? Anyway I provide another way for you that you can try

Comment: I've fixed my question with more cases.  `ARRAY_TO_STRING` is a good solution, but has a limit(*substr* cann't contains delimiter)