# How to check, is (value) in postgres sql (array)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have an array in SQL like

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
examples text ARRAY);

INSERT INTO Table1 
(examples)
VALUES
{t1,t2,t3};
```

I can't find a description of the correct syntax to do `select * from Table1  where (values) in (any\some)` examples
I tried the tutorial example but it doesn't work or I just don't understand something

```
select *
from player_scores
where 95 < any (round_scores);
```

Do I understand correctly that you need to do something like this -

[Postgresql Select rows where column = array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738446/postgresql-select-rows-where-column-array)
or this -
[How to check if any field of array not contains substring in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71647754/how-to-check-if-any-field-of-array-not-contains-substring-in-postgres)

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE "value" = any (examples);
```

Comment: You need to use single quotes instead of double quotes  https://dbfiddle.uk/oiD2UpVP

Comment: Done! SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE 'VALUE' = ANY(examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to check, is (value) in postgres sql (array)?

Yes, it is correct. if you want to check whether a value is in a PostgreSQL array, you can use function `ANY()`. `ANY()` returns true if the value is present in the array, and false otherwise.

Furthermore you need to use single quotes instead of double quotes when using `ANY()` with arrays in PostgreSQL. The reason is `ANY()` expects the array elements to be enclosed in single` quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM player_scores WHERE '95' = ANY(round_scores);
```

Answer (score 1):

[DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TaDjXRcz)

Your query should be:

```
select *
from player_scores
where '95' = ANY(round_scores);
```

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39643544/20666497) too.